# single expression to read value of element in XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextreader

consider the part of xml file.

```
<Element>Value</Element>
```

i used XmlTextReader to read xml file. so i used `while(reader.Read())`

now when i reach `Element` i want to get its Value.

```
if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "Element")
{
     reader.Read();
     var var = reader.Value;
}
```

is there any way to combine this two lines? a single expression equals to:

```
     reader.Read();
     var var = reader.Value;
```

Note that i dont want to skip into Element. i am using XmlTextReader and i read xml line by line.

the only reason is to keep the code simple. i feel better if this be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create an extension method

```
public static string ReadValue(this XmlTextReader reader) 
{
  reader.Read();
  return reader.Value;
}
```

Usage:

```
if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "Element")
{
     var var = reader.ReaderValue();
}
```